# JavaScript loop updating the value of string mysteriously

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have built a function that returns `"YES"` or `"NO"` based on some input.
The input is a string of brackets that should be balanced.

Example:

Balanced - { [ ( ) ] }
 Non-balanced - { [ ( ] ) }

The function is returning `undefined` for this call.

> isBalanced('{[(])}');

Tired of debugging. I am sure there is something wrong inside the loop.

```
function isBalanced(s) {
    let brackets = s.split('');
    let balanced = "YES";
    const closedBrackets = ')]}';
    const bracketCompliment = {
        '(' : ')',
        '[' : ']',
        '{' : '}'
    };
    for(let idx = 0; idx < brackets.length; idx++){
        const item = brackets.splice(0, 1)[0];
        if(closedBrackets.includes(item)){
            balanced = "NO";   
            return;
        }
        const closeIdx = brackets.indexOf(bracketCompliment[item]);
        const remainder = closeIdx % 2;
        if(closeIdx === -1 || remainder !== 0){
            balanced = "NO";
            return;
        } else{
            brackets.splice(closeIdx, 1);
        }
    }
    return balanced;
}
```

Comment: Man this has been a very common question over the last few weeks.

Comment: Replace the `return`s with `break`s in the `for` loop

Comment: `return;` <-- well returning undefined

Comment: Is that a code challenge?

Comment: btw I think your code doesn't work. I ran your function after fixing the returns and sometimes it gives a wrong result.

Comment: That's correct @Guywhotypesfast. it fails on some balanced strings as well, anyways, the first hurdle is crossed.

Comment: It was asked in an interview. @JonasWilms

Comment: This is something you learn in school. You solve this with a stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `return balanced;` and no `return;`

```js
function isBalanced(s) {
  let brackets = s.split('');

  const closedBrackets = ')]}';

  const bracketCompliment = {
    '(': ')',
    '[': ']',
    '{': '}',
  };

  for (let idx = 0; idx < brackets.length; idx += 1) {
    const item = brackets.splice(0, 1)[0];

    if (closedBrackets.includes(item)) {
      return 'NO';
    }

    const closeIdx = brackets.indexOf(bracketCompliment[item]);

    if (closeIdx === -1 || closeIdx % 2 !== 0) {
      return 'NO';
    }
    
    brackets.splice(closeIdx, 1);
  }

  return 'YES';
}

console.log(isBalanced('{[(])}'));
console.log(isBalanced('{()}'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach to your problem

```js
let str = "{[()]}";

function isBalanced(str) {
    const s = str.replace(/[^{}\][()]/, '').split(""),
        codes = {'123': 125,'91': 93,'40': 41};
    if (s.length % 2 !== 0) return 'NO';
    const [first, last] = [s.splice(0, s.length / 2), s];
    return first.every((e,i) => codes[e.charCodeAt(0)] === last[last.length - (i+1)].charCodeAt(0)) ? 'YES' : 'NO'
}

console.log(isBalanced(str));
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```js
function isBalanced (str) {
  const obj = {'{': '}', '[': '}', '(': ')'}

  // if (str.length % 2) return 'NO'
  if (obj[str[0]] === str[str.length - 1]) {
    if (str.length === 2) return 'YES'
    return isBalanced(str.slice(1, -1))
  }
  
  return 'NO'
}

console.log(isBalanced('{[(])}'));
console.log(isBalanced('{()}'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put a `return` inside a function, that function will stop right there if it ever gets to that part of the code and it will return what you put in that return statement, since you don't give any value in those `return`s inside the loop it returns `undefined`.

You can avoid this by simply removing those lines and leaving only one return at the end of your code:

```
function isBalanced(s) {
    let brackets = s.split('');
    let balanced = "YES";
    const closedBrackets = ')]}';
    const bracketCompliment = {
        '(' : ')',
        '[' : ']',
        '{' : '}'
    };
    for(let idx = 0; idx < brackets.length; idx++){
        const item = brackets.splice(0, 1)[0];
        if(closedBrackets.includes(item)){
            balanced = "NO";   
        }
        const closeIdx = brackets.indexOf(bracketCompliment[item]);
        const remainder = closeIdx % 2;
        if(closeIdx === -1 || remainder !== 0){
            balanced = "NO";
        } else{
            brackets.splice(closeIdx, 1);
        }
    }
    return balanced;
}
```

Now your function will wait until the loop is finished and will return whatever was assigned last to `balanced`.

I hope this helps.

**Note:** If you want to break out of the loop you can use `break` instead of  `return`.

Comment: So you mean I should not update the value of variable balanced inside the loop ?

Comment: The value is being updated, but if you use an empty return it will break out of the function and give undefined as a result, if you use a break instead it will break out of the loop and continue right after it.

Answer (score 0):

You are only returning the value of `balanced` when the input string actually is balanced. In both cases where you set `balanced = "NO"` you immediately return with no value. If you replace these `return` statements with `break` statements, the function behaves as expected.

```
function isBalanced(s) {
    let brackets = s.split('');
    let balanced = "YES";
    const closedBrackets = ')]}';
    const bracketCompliment = {
        '(' : ')',
        '[' : ']',
        '{' : '}'
    };
    for (let idx = 0; idx < brackets.length; idx++) {
      const item = brackets.splice(0, 1)[0];
      if (closedBrackets.includes(item)) {
        balanced = "NO";
        break;
      }
      const closeIdx = brackets.indexOf(bracketCompliment[item]);
      const remainder = closeIdx % 2;
      if (closeIdx === -1 || remainder !== 0){
        balanced = "NO";
        break;
      } else{
        brackets.splice(closeIdx, 1);
      }
    }

    return balanced;
}
```